# Why does spring-kafka depend on kotlin-stdlib?

Tags: spring-kafka

Since version **2.7.0** the spring-kafka library pulls the `kotlin-stdlib` jar.

This is pom version **2.6.9** not having such dependency: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/kafka/spring-kafka/2.6.9/spring-kafka-2.6.9.pom

And this is pom version **2.7.0** with the new kotlin dependency: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/kafka/spring-kafka/2.7.0/spring-kafka-2.7.0.pom

Since there are no `.kt` files in the main source code I think adding kotlin as a compile dependency is an error.
I also excluded it in my project without any issue.

I ask because the github project says to ask in SO when in doubt.
So is this dependency unnecessary and if not what's its purpose?

Comment: “without any issue” – possibly without any _immediate_ issue. The Kotlin library contains some classes that can be used from Java. I don’t know about spring-kafka, it may well be a mistake there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly not intentional, the only change I can see in the gradle build script is an update to the kotlin version.

There is no reference to `kotlin-stdlib` in build.gradle, only

```
testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8'
```

Comment: It's caused by a change to the Gradle Kotlin Plugin. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1852

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Gary.